# Slot headers vuetify 2.0

Tags: vue.js, datatable, header, vuetify.js, slot

Good morning, I am modifying the slot header of a data table in vuetify.js to add a tooltip, all this does it well, but the arrows of asc and desc are not shown, I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

```
<template  v-slot:header="{ props: { headers } }">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th 
                style="white-space: nowrap"
                :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
                @click="changeSort(header.value)"
                v-for="element in headers" 
                :key="element.text">
                <v-tooltip top>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                        <span v-on="on">{{element.text}}</span>
                    </template>
                    <span>{{element.text}}</span>
                </v-tooltip>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</template>
```

Comment: You should mention which version of Vuetify you're using, a number of things changed in 2.0.

Comment: sorry, version is 2.2.21

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots),

> It is important to note some slot (eg: `item`/`body`/`header`) will completely takes over the internal rendering of the component which will require you to re-implement functionalities such as selection and expansion.

But you can [customize the default header](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#customizing-default-header)

> You can use the dynamic slots header. to customize only certain columns.  is the name of the value property in the corresponding header item sent to headers.

Modifying the codepen in that second section of the documentation, you can see how you can add tooltips for each header, using [dynamic slot names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names).  Here I have a tooltip for the first 3 columns, and just the default text for the remaining columns, but populating a tooltip text for all in `headerTooltips` will produce tooltips for all headers.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]="{ header }">
        <v-tooltip v-if="headerTooltips[header.value]" bottom :key="header.value">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <span v-on="on">{{ header.text }}</span>
          </template>
          <span>{{ headerTooltips[header.value] }}</span>
        </v-tooltip>
        <span v-else>{{ header.text }}<span>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'start',
        value: 'name',
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
    ],
    headerTooltips: {
      name: 'Name tooltip',
      calories: 'Calories tooltip',
      fat: 'Fat tooltip'
    },
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Eclair',
        calories: 262,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 23,
        protein: 6.0,
        iron: '7%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Cupcake',
        calories: 305,
        fat: 3.7,
        carbs: 67,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '8%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Gingerbread',
        calories: 356,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 49,
        protein: 3.9,
        iron: '16%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Jelly bean',
        calories: 375,
        fat: 0.0,
        carbs: 94,
        protein: 0.0,
        iron: '0%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Lollipop',
        calories: 392,
        fat: 0.2,
        carbs: 98,
        protein: 0,
        iron: '2%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Honeycomb',
        calories: 408,
        fat: 3.2,
        carbs: 87,
        protein: 6.5,
        iron: '45%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Donut',
        calories: 452,
        fat: 25.0,
        carbs: 51,
        protein: 4.9,
        iron: '22%',
      },
      {
        name: 'KitKat',
        calories: 518,
        fat: 26.0,
        carbs: 65,
        protein: 7,
        iron: '6%',
      },
    ],
  }),
})
```

Here is that Codepen: https://codepen.io/keeganwitt/pen/ExVVyqa

Comment: This is great! However, when I try and add to example here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#crud-actions it raise exception "Unexpected identifier" and I think it refers to the v-slot header syntax. A reference link to how to interpret syntax `[\`header.${header.value}\`]` in `v-slot:[\`header.${header.value}\`]="{ header }"`would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: BTW... I am using inside template: \`....\` so I think I need to escape the backticks or implement alternative?

Comment: What I came up with is escaping the backticks AND the `$` - this `<template v-for="h in headers" v-slot:[\`header.${h.value}\`]="{ header }">` becomes `<template v-for="h in headers" v-slot:[\\`header.\${h.value}\\`]="{ header }">`

Comment: Are you using some kind of template preprocessor? I don't see this issue. Do note that the dynamic slot names requires Vue 2.6. There are some character restrictions, but in the example I have above, I'm not using any of those characters. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Argument-Value-Constraints.

Comment: I am using this within the context of SAP XSA.  What I know is that without escaping the backticks and the `$` found inside of the backticks used to declare the template within the vue component, they are incorrectly interpreted rendering the logic invalid.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that. I'd need to know more about how it's being packaged for that environment. If it works I guess  /shrugs

Comment: I am using vue component and assigning the template to property of the component using backticks. Would be interested to learn if there is another way to factor the work so that I can use a separate HTML file. Angular allows, but I can't see same in vue. Cheers!